# SQL Query ignores WHERE online = '0'

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a simple SQL Query in my PHP Code. 
The %search% is a input where the user is able to write something.

My problem is that the online = '0' gets ignored and there are also Data with online = '1'

```
$sql = "SELECT * from baw.entrys WHERE online = '0' and title like '%search%' or weight like '%search%' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

If I take the or away and leave my SQL Query like this it works.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from baw.entrys WHERE online = '0' and title like '%search%' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: parenthesis are your friend in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) so your first `WHERE` actually looks like

```
(online = '0' and title like '%search%') or weight like '%search%'
```

which means it will match any row where `weight` is like `%search%`, regardless of the value of `online`. What you actually want is:

```
online = '0' and (title like '%search%' or weight like '%search%')
```

so just change the `WHERE` clause to be like the above line and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * from baw.entrys WHERE online = '0' and (title like '%search%' or weight like '%search%') ORDER BY id DESC";
```

You need to use parenthesis for your `OR` statement otherwise the `OR` will also include your `online = '0'`.

You are facing this error because in your code you look for `online` column to be 0

and `title` to be like search  OR the `weight` to be like search so if it find the weight column to be like search it will include it no matter what the other values are cause it become true.

Have a look at this thread about [true/false table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583853/true-and-false-for-logic-and-logic-table) and you will realize what was wrong pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend

```
$sql = "SELECT * from baw.entrys WHERE online = '0' and (title like '%search%' or weight like '%search%') ORDER BY id DESC"
```